# Tomcat rewrite valve issue

Tags: tomcat, url-rewriting, tomcat8

Rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w)/(\w)/(\w)$ index.php/$1/$2/$3
```

Test URI:

```
http://localhost/foo/bar/snafu
```

Expected result:

```
http://localhost/index.php/foo/bar/snafu
```

The rule doesn't seem to be matching at all.  What did I do wrong?

On a related note, is there any way to log rewrite rule hits with the tomcat rewrite valve?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems here. `/` is a delimiter, so you need to use `\/` if you want to match a forward slash in the URL. Since the syntax isn't valid, the rule will be skipped, and that request won't be passed to PHP.

Also, `\w` represents a single word-character (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or _). So you'd only match if `/f/b/s` were the request. What you need is `+`, which matches one or more of what immediately precedes it - in this case, `\w`.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)$ index.php/$1/$2/$3
```